# Code collaborator Error while parsing xml

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, code-collaborator

[image]

This is the error I am getting while adding changes. 
This is in the error log:

> Could not determine if checkout D:\cm\Everest\2 is managed by
>   Subversion: Error while parsing XML

The folder is definitely SVN managed, so I have no clue what the problem is.
I found somewhat similar errors online, but none exactly like this one.

Update:

I used checkout on a new folder and merged my changes from my other folder into the new one and I was able to checkout. Took some time, but should work in the end.

Comment: If it works with svn.exe or TortoiseSVN but does not work with Collaborator, contact Collaborator's support for assistance.

Comment: @bahrep Yes I know, that what it says. I was hoping someone here had the same problem.